# C# XmlWriter WriteStartAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I want to write to following tag into an XML file.

```
<StructureMetaData xsi:schemaLocation="MSD" xmlns="MSD" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <!-- here a following more tags -->
</StructureMetaData>
```

for these I do the following

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "\t"
    CheckCharacters = false,
};

XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create (filename, settings);

xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument ();
xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute ("xsi", "schemaLocation", "MSD");
xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute ("xmlns", "MSD");
xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute ("xmlns", "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

But after the first call of WriteStartAttribute I got the following exception:

> "Token StartAttribute in the status document would result in an invalid XML document."

How can write these attributes into the xml tag?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues:

1. You need to write the [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) tag `<StructureMetaData` **first**, before you start writing any of its attributes.  There is a default namespace `xmlns="MSD"` so you'll need to write it in that namespace.
2. You are calling [`XmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartattribute.aspx), however this method only writes an attribute **name**.  You still have to write the **value** after the name using, e.g., [`XmlWriter.WriteString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring.aspx).  Alternatively, you could write the name and value with one call to [`XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring.aspx).
3. You should close and dispose of your `xmlWriter` via a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.

Here is a working version of your code using `WriteStartAttribute()`:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    var rootNamespace = "MSD";

    // Write the root element in the MSD namespace
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("StructureMetaData", rootNamespace);

    // Write the root element's attribute names and values
    xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    xmlWriter.WriteString("MSD");
    xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute("xmlns");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(rootNamespace);
    xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute("xmlns", "xsi", null);
    xmlWriter.WriteString("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    // Write the root element contents

    // Close the root element
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    // Close the document
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

And a simpler version using `WriteAttributeString()`:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    var rootNamespace = "MSD";

    // Write the root element in the MSD namespace
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("StructureMetaData", rootNamespace);

    // Write the root element's attribute names and values
    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "MSD");
    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", rootNamespace);
    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    // Write the root element contents

    // Close the root element
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    // Close the document
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xj6XmE) showing both options.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I have had some problems with more than 2 arguments by WriteAttributeString

Comment: @Holgis - you're welcome.  If the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147531).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write a start *element* on which the attributes are written:

```
xmlWriter.WritestartElement("StructureMetaData");
xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication72
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string root = "<StructureMetaData xsi:schemaLocation=\"MSD\" xmlns=\"MSD\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"></StructureMetaData>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(root);
            XElement metaData = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = metaData.GetDefaultNamespace();

            metaData.Add(new XElement(ns + "ABC", new object[] {
                new XElement(ns + "DEF", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("rst","abc"),
                    123}),
                new XElement(ns + "GHI", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("uvw","def"),                    
                    456}),
                new XElement(ns + "JKL", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("xyz","ghi"),
                    789})
            }));

            doc.Save("filename");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But with the subitems <ABC> I have a xml problem. I got the following:
<StructureMetaData xsi:schemaLocation="MSD" xmlns="MSD" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  ABC
  <DEF xmlns="">123</DEF>
  <GHI xmlns="">456</GHI>
  <JKL xmlns="">789</JKL>
</StructureMetaData>

I will read how to generate XML files with Linq. Each XElement has an xmlns Attribute.